# composite unique key with one nullable column in DB2

Tags: database, db2

I have two columns in my table and I need to make combination of these columns to be unique. One column may contain null value.
The composite unique key works fine with oracle but its giving error with DB2.
Could anyone please help with how this uniqueness could be achieve in DB2.

Comment: show your table-DDL or minimal example, and your 'create unique index' statement and mention your Db2-version and the operating-system that runs the Db2-server (Z/OS, i-Series, Linux/Unix/Windows).

Comment: Unique constraints on columns that can hold NULL values are not a great idea. In Db2 use a `UNIQUE INDEX` which won't allow a FK to reference it. As Oracle says "Note: It is possible for a foreign key consisting of multiple columns to allow one of the columns to contain a value for which there is no matching value in the referenced columns,  To avoid this situation, create NOT NULL constraints on all of the foreign key's columns"  https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a mimimal example of creating a unique-index containing two columns one of which is not-null and the other is nullable:

```
create table mytable (a integer not null, b integer , c varchar(128) );

create unique index mytableidx on mytable(a,b) ;
```